# How could I fix this problem(Roblox Gui's)

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I decided to make a lua script for my game that would assign a random number to a player and set a guis text to the number. To the left of the random number gui, I put another gui that said "your number is". The problem is, the number gui keeps either getting squished into the "your number is" gui, or is super far from it. I tried setting the anchor point to 0.5, 0.5 and setting the offset to 0(for both of them). It still didnt work. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Before asking a question, please read the [How to ask Section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specify your problem in a way that is easy to understand and try to provide pictures and other necessary resources.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is not a place to ask GUI-related questions if they aren't constructed with code. Only ask programming questions here. The [Roblox DevForum](https://devforum.roblox.com/) is a place you can ask about these.

Comment: Quick question, what do I click to ask a question on the dev forum?

Comment: @Kwallcoder you need to use the DevForum for a while to be able to post a question. Because of your current situation, I'll answer here: You don't need two labels, instead, you can just set the text of a label to `"your number is " .. numbervariablegoeshere`. Alternatively, you can keep using two labels, but with the [`TextXAlignment`](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/TextLabel#TextXAlignment) property set accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gui gets rescaled due to the size of monitors and game display in studio. I recommend you combine the guis and use string concatenation to combine the text.

Your code should look something like this in a local script inside a text label/box that you want to have the text:

```
local randomNumber = math.random(1, 10)
local gui = script.Parent

gui.Text = "Your number is: "..randomNumber
```